# Firebase querying data like multiple where in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "Events" : {
    "16" : { 
      "eventDate" : "2021-02-02",
      "eventId" : "16",
      "eventName" : "First Test",
      "eventTime" : "09:39:00"
    },
    "22" : {
      "eventDate" : "2021-02-02",
      "eventId" : "22",
      "eventName" : "Test22 Exam",
      "eventTime" : "09:39:00"
    },
    "26" : {
      "eventDate" : "2021-02-02",
      "eventId" : "26",
      "eventName" : "Webinar",
      "eventTime" : "09:39:00"
    }
  }
}
```

If I'm storing my `Events` like this, and I want to get the node where `EventId` is equal to 16 and 26.
How can I do that?

The above is the child of issue, which is a child of root.

I Tried with equalTo but get only single record. **I need to get 16 and 26 both.**

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = reference.child("Events").orderByChild("eventId").equalTo("16");
```

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can achieve this. You might also try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries).

Comment: @AlexMamo: I actually don't think this is a duplicate of the question you marked, as here OP is trying to do an OR of multiple values, not an AND across multiple properties. Using Firestore is a valid option for this type of query though.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Even if the OP wrote "16 and 26", yes, it's an OR rather than an AND. Btw, so happy to see DatabaseReference#get() and Query#get(), added in the Firebase Realtime Database SDK December's update. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, `get()` slipped into the Android SDKs a bit earlier than expected, so we're still catching up with doc and a blog post. More small improvements to the RTDB SDKs are coming up.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can't wait to see them :)

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't support ORs in its queries. The only way to get multiple nodes based on the values of a specific property would be to use a `startAt` and `endAt` to select a range of values, but in your case that would also return the node with `eventId` equal to `22`.

Given that the keys of the nodes are the same as your `eventId` properties, the fastest way I can think of to retrieve multiple nodes is by using a separate `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` or `get()` call for each key:

```
reference.child("Events").child("16").get(...)
reference.child("Events").child("26").get(...)
```

Retrieving multiple child nodes like this is quite fast in Firebase, as all requests are sent over a single, existing socket connection. For more on this, see [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).